# What does a copula density explain about dependence of random variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function, copula

I am studying copulas and I find it difficult to understand what a copula density tells me about the dependence of random variables.

For example, if I have a Gaussian copula density, what can I say about the dependence. How do I even interpret this picture?

[image]

Comment: You need to describe what this plot represents.  It certainly isn't the graph of a copula!  What exactly is it?

Comment: @whuber This is the copula density, which we obtain after differentiation of the Gaussian copula.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the copula density is a density and can be interpreted as any other density. Specifically, with  the density you have shown us, clearly the conditional distribution of one variable depends on the other, so there is dependence, not independence. Further, the density is higher (highest) for (0,0) and (1,1), and lowest for (1,0) and (0,1), so we have  a positive correlation.

Comment: the higher density in the tails demonstrate positive correlation for extreme values. what does the higher density in the tails say about **tail dependence**, given that copulas allow for a separation between the concepts of correlation and tail dependence?